# Modifing a graph generated using scatterplot3d

Tags: r

I use `scatterplot3d` to generate the following graph. Currently, all of the lines are plotted by starting from the bottom surface, which is associated with `value=-1`.

I would like to remove the top surface (associated with `value=5`) and the bottom surface (associated with `value=-1`). In addition, I would like those lines are plotted by starting from the surface associated with `value=0`.  Are there any approaches to help me achieve this?

[image]

The data and code for generating this graph are as follows:

```
s3d.dat <- read.table(text="
   V1 V2 V3
   1  2 -1
   2  1  0
   1  1  2
   1  5 -1
   5  1  0",header=TRUE)

library(scatterplot3d)

s3d<-scatterplot3d(s3d.dat,type="h",pch=8,color="red")
s3d$plane3d(0,0,0)
```